# Stored procedure to run a query based off timestamp in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a procedure where the query will only run if the table has been updated at a certain time.

There is actually a timestamp in the table so I just need to check something like

```
IF table.update = GETDATE() THEN …
```

I'm not even sure where to start here.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a place where I can learn about stuff like this, or show me which functions I need to use?

Comment: I mean, Google is a place to start. "SQL Server find records after certain time" should suffice?

Comment: I know how to query based off dates. This is a stored procedure that will run based on the time, and if the time is incorrect the procedure will not run. It's for automating email lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by looking at how to use Database JOBs.
 Since no stored procedure can start by itself.

Inside the Job, you can define how often and when stored procedure run.

The code inside the job can be simple SQL.

OR

You can create an update Trigger on the table. And inside the trigger base on the time call the stored procedure.

Update:

Just saw your latest comment. I have a similar app in my company. We use a Database Job to send a batch of auotmated emails on specific time everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger, in the UPDATE method, and you can have it run when it is saved in a separate table.
The new table must have the primary key and the time stamp with the GETDATE () method.
To Implement the Trigger:

```
create trigger trTriggerTest on tableName after update
As
Begin
   set nocount on;
  INSERT INTO TimeRegister(Id, date, ...) VALUES (@Id, GetDate(), ...);
end
go
```

To register en new table:

```
INSERT INTO TimeRegister(Id, date, ...) VALUES (@Id, GetDate(), ...);
```

Documentation: [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)